# Is there a way to change the color of the arrow/twistie of the Details element by using HTML only?

Tags: html, styles

I am using the details element in HTML and I can't use CSS. Only HTML.

```
<details>
    <summary>Details</summary>
    Something small enough to escape casual notice.
</details>
```

This gives me a black arrow. Will it be possible to change the color or the arrow and maybe the size/styling using HTML only? I can't use CSS.

Comment: You can't do that without using CSS. HTML is only meant to define the structure of the document, styling is supposed to be done in CSS. So in general it's not possible to change the style of anything without using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

No.
The default element is black, in order to change it, you must use CSS.
You can use CSS inline in the HTML, by adding to the style tag